# Ошибка при создании калькулятора

Tags: python, калькулятор

После создания калькулятора решил его обновить, добавив цикл, но пишет ошибку.

```
while True:
    what = input("Действие:")
    a = float(input("Первое число:"))
    b = float(input("Второе число:"))
    if what === "+":
        c = a + b
        print("Результат: " + str(c))
    elif what == "-":
        c = a - b
        print("Результат: " + str(c))
    elif what == "*":
        c = a * b
        print("Результат: " + str(c))
    elif what == "/":
        c = a / b
        print("Результат: " + str(c))
    elif what == "степень":
        c = a ** b
        print("Результат: " + str(c))
    elif what, a, b == 'выход' "Выход":
        break
    else:
        print("Выбрана неверная операция!")
input()
```

В командной строке пишет:

```
File "C:\Users\Asus\Videos\Python\Calculator.py", line 3
    a = float(input("Первое число:"))
                                     ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: 1) Не надо было новый вопрос открывать, надо старый редактировать. 2) Вы проверку на то, что везде 4 пробела, а не табулятор, выполнили? (вам писали об этом)

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: Обратите внимание на будущее, PEP-8 рекомендует использовать только пробелы.

Comment: ``elif what, a, b == 'выход' "Выход":`` почему вы вдруг решили, что так можно писать?

Comment: Я просто экспериментировал

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` говорит, о том, что у вас проблема в табуляции. Возможно вы везде использовали `Tab`, а в строке с ошибкой пробелы или наоборот.